# bootstrap-4.0 table tr class d-flex not working properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

**bootstrap-4.0 table tr class d-flex not working properly in Firefox browser but working in chrome. 
I have attached my code chrome working fine
But Firefox browser not working properly 
I am using 
 - bootstrap 4.0
 - HTML-5
 - CSS3**

bootstrap-4.0 table tr class d-flex not working properly in Firefox browser but working in chrome. 
I have attached my code chrome working fine
But Firefox browser not working properly 
I am using 
 - bootstrap 4.0
 - HTML-5
 - CSS3

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
<div class="col-12 table-responsive">
       <table class="table total_records table-bordered">
         <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <th class="text-center col-2">Start Date</th>
          <th class="text-center col-2">End Date</th>
          <th class="text-center col-2">Absence Type</th>        
          <th class="text-center col-1">Days</th>
          <th class="text-center col-2">Status</th>
          <th class="text-center col-3">Action</th>
        </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>         
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Regularization</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Permission</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Rejected</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Sick</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Pending</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="d-flex">
          <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
          <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
          <td class="col-1">5</td>
          <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
          <td class="col-3 text-center">
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
         <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
            </div></div>
```

```
<div class="col-12 table-responsive">
                        <table class="table total_records table-bordered">
                          <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <th class="text-center col-2">Start Date</th>
                              <th class="text-center col-2">End Date</th>
                              <th class="text-center col-2">Absence Type</th>                               
                              <th class="text-center col-1">Days</th>
                              <th class="text-center col-2">Status</th>
                              <th class="text-center col-3">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>                             
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Regularization</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Permission</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Rejected</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Sick</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Pending</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="d-flex">
                              <td class="col-2">08/20/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">08/24/2018</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Casual</td>
                              <td class="col-1">5</td>
                              <td class="col-2">Approved</td>
                              <td class="col-3 text-center">
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon" onclick="openNav('2')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span class="calendar-table-icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How to fixed..,.